# Cannot Point Android Studio to Java 1.8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtual-machine

A lot of the new Android Studio / Android features require Java 1.8.

I have followed the instructions located [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Xor.png), and notice that my Android Studio is not allowing me to point to the folder location containing Java 1.8. When I get to the folder where it is located, it does not let me drill down any further:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice the location of the currently selected Java 7 home - under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, not `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/`. AFAIK, the applet plugin does not in itself contain an entire JDK that you can reference from Android Studio. What directories are inside your `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the location of the currently selected Java 7 home - under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, not `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/`.

AFAIK, the applet plugin does not in itself contain an entire JDK that you can reference from Android Studio. You can verify this by looking at and comparing the contents of `Contents/Home/bin` in each location, the Home in `Internet Plug-Ins` does not contain standard Java *Development* Kit tools such as `javac` - the Java compiler tool.

What directories are inside your `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder? It looks like you already have Java 7, which is what's currently selected. Look for something referencing `jdk1.8.0` - Java 8. If that directory is present, select it as your Java 8 JDK. If not, you don't already have the Java 8 JDK installed and you'll need to install it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Doesn't the second (sorry it is kind of hard to distinguish) image in my question show that I have Java 1.8?

Comment: No, where are you seeing an "8" anywhere? Look at your file tree, you're in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`. That folder is just what it says it is, an Applet Plugin, not a JDK. You need to go to the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.

Comment: Look to the very left where it says "Product" and "Platform"

Comment: Oh, I see what you're thinking - I never even saw that image. Unfortunately, the problem remains. The system might be intelligent enough to recognize that the plugin is based on Java 8, but it still is just that, a plugin - not a JDK. Open up the explorer shown in your third image and select `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`, then tell me what's there.

Comment: Ok, making progress! That means you just don't have the 1.8 JDK, and need to download it from the link mentioned near the end of my answer. Once that's installed, a folder for JDK 1.8 should show up in that directory, which you can select.

Comment: What is the difference between 8u101 and 8u102?

Comment: The u stands for "Update", so it's Java 8 update 101 or update 102. Since 102 is newer, I'd probably go with that.

Comment: Personally, I don't see why you would want to. There isn't really any harm in leaving it and you may not know what applications you have that have issues with Java 8 or require Java 7 for some reason.